# Conditional regex for extracting strings and numbers from URI

Tags: ruby, regex

I have URI strings which look like this (`etc` can be of any length):

```
/7/ipsum/dolor/etc
/2/not/17/ipsum/etc
```

Here is what I am trying to achieve: split the strings on forward slashes, take the second and the third matches (`["ipsum", "dolor"]` and `["not", "17"]`), throw away the second element if it is not a number. The desired results are `["ipsum"]` and `["not", "17"]`.

I implemented this with plain ruby (by splitting the string into an array and then checking values for the desired value). Is there a better way to do this with regex?

Comment: I think it's better to do it your way

Comment: please give us the full `URL`s.

Comment: There is a URI module that allows for simple parsing. Have you considered that?

Comment: [PCRE PHP demo](http://regex101.com/r/lP0uC2). [Ruby demo](http://rubular.com/r/MygZGnX1Rs).

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV Awesome — it does the job and regex is sure cleaner than if-else loop. Will you make the comment an answer so I could accept it?

Comment: @Priti, "please give us the full URLs"? Why? The OP is working from the path of the URI exclusively, so a full URL won't make a difference.

Comment: It's expected that you would supply a sample of the code you're using. It's always better for us to help you fix code you're using, than for us to supply completely new code that to be retrofitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possible implementation, with an expanded, documented regex.

```
def extract_parts_from(path)
  pattern = %r{
    ^/[^/]+     # don't capture the first element
     /([^/]+)   # always capture the second element
     /(?:(\d+)/)?    # capture the third element if it's made up of digits
  }x
  path.match(pattern)[1,2].compact
end
```

test:

```
["/7/ipsum/dolor/etc", "/2/not/17/ipsum/etc"]. each do |p|
  p extract_parts_from(p)
end
```

results:

```
["ipsum"]
["not", "17"]
```

Comment: The 3rd line can be simplified a bit to: `/(?:(\d+)/)?`

Comment: indeed. That was still in there from an earlier version. changing it now.

Answer (score 2):

## Description

This expression will return the second value, and the third value if it's numeric.

`^/(?:[^/]*/){1}([^/]*)/(?:(\d{1,})|[^/]*)/.*?$`

`^\/(?:[^\/]*\/){1}([^\/]*)\/(?:(\d{1,})|[^\/]*)\/.*?$` this is the same expression however the forward slashes have been escaped as some languages need that

[image]

- `^` match the beginning of a line
- `/` match a forward slash
- `(?:[^/]*/)` match a group of text followed by a slash, this group is matched by a not captured
- `{1}` although functionally the same as `+` this gives the dev the ability to select X number of slash delimited fields to skip over by simply changing the value inside the brackets
- `([^/]*)` capture the string of non slashes
- `/` match the slash
- `(?:` start a non captured group, this allows the `or` condition to match just the contained expression
- `(\d{1,})` capture a group of digits, although functionally the same as `+` this gives the dev the ability to select a minimum and if desired maximum number of digits which must be present by simply changing the the values inside the brackets
- `|` or
- `[^/]* match a group of text`
   `)` end of non captured group
- `/` match the next slash
- `.*?$` matches the remaining string up to the end of a line.

## Groups

0 receives the entire matched string

1. receives the second value
2. receives the third value providing it's a number

## Disclaimer

I don't Ruby, so I'm including a php example to demonstrate that the expression does work.

## PHP Code Example:

```
<?php
$sourcestring="/7/ipsum/dolor/etc
/2/not/17/ipsum/etc";
preg_match_all('/^\/(?:[^\/]*\/){1}([^\/]*)\/(?:(\d{1,})|[^\/]*)\/.*?$/im',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>

$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => /7/ipsum/dolor/etc
            [1] => /2/not/17/ipsum/etc
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => ipsum
            [1] => not
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 17
        )

)
```

Comment: Overly complicated: putting `{1}` after an expression is meaningless, `{1,}` is the same as +, and the `.*` at the end is not useful.

Comment: yes, using {1} in this case is meaningless, however it does give the programmer the ability to simply select the number of fields they'd like to skip over before starting to match. Including or excluding it doesn't change final output or overall functionality.

Comment: The `.*` at the end allows the regex to be used against a string with many values. Yes, if the input string was a single value then the `.*` would be unnecessary. Since OP's sample doesn't specify strings with a single uri, then this solution solves the question as asked.

Comment: Take a look at Mark Hubbart's answer to learn how to clean this up.